# How to force drupal to use English version of the field?

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n, blocks

I have bean block with a list (list_block) of other bean blocks (content_block) which I use in slider. I have multilingual site, so I have 2 languages English and Spanish. Each content_block has translation (so it has both English and Spanish variants). So the problem is:

I have an empty field Description in one of my content_blocks and it's empty only for English version, but it has data in Spanish version. So when I go to see the slider (with the list of content_blocks) on my homepage in English version I see Spanish value of this field but not empty value. When I add English value to that field the problem disappearing and English value appears in the slider. So why this happening? And **how to force Drupal to use English version of the field even if it has no value but it has Spanish version of the field** ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Views admin of the block, and filter by language. It will automatically only show the node in the language that you select.